# AngularJS: Get value from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get value from response JSON data. How can i get the values `domain`, `status`, `key`.

**Response JSON data:**

```
{"example.com":{"status":"YES","key":"example"}}
```

**Angular JS Code**

```
$http.post('http://exampleURL.com', postData).success(function(response){
     console.log(response);
     alert();
   }).error(function() {

   });
```

Comment: Are you able to see response?

Comment: If you are able to see response as {"example.com":{"status":"YES","key":"example"}} then simply access it using . operator

Comment: @Mohit: `.` is not an operator, but besides that, it's not possible to access this object using dot notation.

Comment: var response = {"example.com":{"status":"YES","key":"example"}};                                      for( var i in response ){                                                                                console.log(i);  // should give you the domain console.log(response[i].status) // should give you the status                                    }

Comment: @user1999 you welcome. you can mark it as an answer. I could only respond to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

use angular.fromJson to parse JSON then traverse it using **.**

```
$http.post('http://exampleURL.com', postData).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    var data = angular.fromJson(response); 
    console.log(data['example.com'].status);    
}).error(function() {

});
```